# long server call, i don't have response, but it restarts

Tags: php, server, timeout, call, restart

i have an ajax call, that builds a series of xml, and it takes a time variable from 7 to 11 minuts.
When it takes more than a certain times (i can't see axactly, i think about 8/9 minuts), i don't receive the answer, but i see on server that the process restart!

ANy knkow how and how can i avoid it?

That's my call:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: urlQui,
        
        /*dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },/**/
        dataType: "text",
        timeout: 1200000, /* 20 minuts */
        async: true,
        success: function( data ) {

            $("#" + dove).html(data);
        }/**/
    });
```

And those are setting in my php page about timeout:

```
set_time_limit (0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT
```

any help?
thanks

Comment: If the query is heavy, please break it down, and consider that you need to break away the DB and API server.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto: I agree, but what do you mean by: _"break away the DB and API server"_?

Comment: Separate the server as independent server, because well, if the load is high, so breakaway the DB and the API/Web put it on different server. Anyway a good end point is always return result below 10s

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to not do time intensive work in request. Best way to do that is to implement some sort of queue.

You can start by having a database table - something like `job_queue (id, parametersJson)`.

In your script (that is on `$urlQui`) just insert into this table: `INSERT INTO job_queue (parametersJson) VALUES ($request->getBody())`.

Than you'll run another command line PHP script (probably using supervisor on the server) roughly like this:

```
while (true)) {

  $job = $db->fetch('SELECT * FROM job_queue LIMIT 1');
  if (!$job) {
    sleep(10);
    continue;
  }
  $this->generateXml($job['paramateresJson']);
  // do some logging of the job result somewhere

}
```

To make it more resilient you can count the number of cycles in the while loop and kill it every 100 or so to be sure you don't accumulate memory leaks. Supervisor will restart the job as soon as it's killed.

Comment: But I think this is really bad tbh.. :/ PHP aren't designed to run for long time run, and prone to memory leak. I think this should be another piece of code should run on background with native app/code using C# or another lang that works for it. Or use pub/sub like nats.io

Comment: That's why you limit number of iterations it handles. If it ever leaks, it will be reclaimed when restarted. PHP can handle it very well. In background job you don't care about startup time (which is minuscule anyway). 

Adding another tech (like some compiled lang) is completely unnecessary unless you hit the limit. And that's pretty hard to do.